# Specific ethernet cable not working with router only, but works with NIC

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, network-adapter, crossover-cable

I have a DLink DIR-605L, which is a 10/100 Mbps (non-ADSL) router. I am connected to it on a Desktop with a Realtek Network Adapter onboard MSI P45 Platinum. I also have an Asus X54H-SX137D. Both these are able to connect fine to my router.

About 100 feet away, in a different building (next to my house) there's another desktop with an Intel NIC onboard a DG33FB. It is connected by a long Ethernet Cat-5 cable, which my router is refusing to detect.

Note that

- WAN on the router works. Every Ethernet port on the router works, tested with my Realtek NIC.
- The Intel NIC is able to connect to my Realtek NIC as well as my Asus laptop at **1.0 Gbps full duplex**. So obviously all pairs of the cable are crimped firmly.
- BUT the Intel NIC at the other end of the cable is not recognized by the router. As if it wasn't there at all.
- I crimped both T-568A and T-568B orders of crimping, both times link with the NICs was perfect, but link with the router was nonexistent.

How can this happen? Even if Auto-MDI/MDIX isn't enabled on all ports of the router, which I highly doubt, I tried it both ways. Any ideas?

Comment: It's unclear if you're using T-568A on one end, and T-568B on the other end, which makes a cross-over cable, or if you've tried 568A on both sides, as well as 568B on both sides (for straight-thru);  If you can connect host to host over that cable, then it seems its wired cross-over.  This might not work for connecting to a switch.  (Auto crossover detection works more reliably for short jumpers).  If you haven't already, could you try with both sides crimped to either the A std or the B std for a straight-thru cable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was something else entirely.

While experimenting with the other Intel NIC, I had set Speed to 1.0 Gbps instead of Autonegotiation. This resulted in it not being able to connect to the router which is 10/100.

It appears that my router does actually support crossover-detection.

Thanks.